# Package libcurl4-openssl-dev issues on installing R packages Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTE

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, openssl

I installed the package libcurl4-openssl-dev on Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Then created a new miniconda environment *environment* where I installed an older version of R with repsect to the R version I have in the "base" environment.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /home/studenti/miniconda3/envs/biobakery-melonnpan/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.12.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1
```

I wanted to install a list of packages, using:

```
R -q -e "install.packages(c('devtools', 'glmnet', 'foreach', 'getopt', 'doParallel', 'vegan', 'data.table', 'ggplot2', 'AssocTests', 'optparse', 'tibble'), repos='http://cran.r-project.org')"
```

But as an Output I obtained that some dependencies for some packages weren't available, and the packages were not installed.

```
ERROR: dependency ‘credentials’ is not available for package ‘gert’
removing ‘/home/studenti/miniconda3/envs/biobakery-melonnpan/lib/R/library/gert’
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘gh’
removing ‘/home/studenti/miniconda3/envs/biobakery-melonnpan/lib/R/library/gh’
ERROR: dependencies ‘systemfonts’, ‘textshaping’ are not available for package ‘ragg’
removing ‘/home/studenti/miniconda3/envs/biobakery-melonnpan/lib/R/library/ragg’
ERROR: dependency ‘fExtremes’ is not available for package ‘AssocTests’
removing ‘/home/studenti/miniconda3/envs/biobakery-melonnpan/lib/R/library/AssocTests’
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘gert’, ‘gh’ are not available for package ‘usethis’
removing ‘/home/studenti/miniconda3/envs/biobakery-melonnpan/lib/R/library/usethis’
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘ragg’ are not available for package ‘pkgdown’
removing ‘/home/studenti/miniconda3/envs/biobakery-melonnpan/lib/R/library/pkgdown’
ERROR: dependencies ‘usethis’, ‘pkgdown’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘rversions’, ‘urlchecker’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
removing ‘/home/studenti/miniconda3/envs/biobakery-melonnpan/lib/R/library/devtools’

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmp1XU3Vb/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in ‘.Library’
Making ‘packages.html’ … done
There were 19 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Trying to install them one by one in R using

```
install.packages(*package*, dependencies=TRUE)
```

has given me the output:

```
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My problem here is that the package libcurl4-openssl-dev is not found when installing R packages and I can't add it to the PATH.
Is there someone that could help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

These are system dependencies, not R packages. If you really want to build your own packages, then you'll need to install `libcurl4-openssl-dev` through apt in this case.

What is generally recommended on Ubuntu though, is not to build the packages yourself, but to get them as ppa as is described on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I followed what is written in the instructions and run ""sudo apt install --no-install-recommends r-cran-devtools"" for example, but I have no package devtools when I try to load it from the library, and I don't knwo if it is really installed or it is in a different path.

Comment: Make sure the package is actually installed. You can do that with `dpkg -s r-cran-devtools | grep Status`

Comment: If it is installed but R still does not find it, enter `dpkg -L r-cran-devtools` in the terminal to check where it was installed. Then check with `.libPaths()` in the R console whether R is looking in the right place